# @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type allowHigherOrderFunctions exception returns error with the same args

Tags: typescript-eslint

Here's the relevant snippet of my `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
"rules": {
     "@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type": [
      "warn",
      {
        "allowHigherOrderFunctions": true
      }
    ],
}
```

With this config I am encountering the following:

```js
// ❌ fails 
const arrowFn1 = (): void => {
  return;
};
export const arrowHoc = () => arrowFn1;

// ✅ passes
export const arrowFn2 = () => (): void => {
  return;
};
```

I thought the top example would work. Is this expected? Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected - the lint rule purposely does not track references to understand what variables might be. The point of the rule is to enforce that you're defining strict contracts in your code - which means declaring return types with the declaration.

`() => (): void => { ... }` is ignored with the option because the return type is trivially inferred from the declaration in code, without any IDE features - it's trivially read as "a function that returns a function that returns void"
However with `() => variable` there isn't the same assurance - instead reading the code you read "a function that returns a variable" - which isn't a strict contract at all!

One could argue that the rule should ignore it because the variable is defined on the preceding line, however the rule takes a clean, consistent approach as opposed to a messy, confusing one based on lots of exceptions. For example imagine instead if your code was

```
import { arrowFn1 } from 'module';
export const arrowHoc = () => arrowFn1;
```

What's the return type of `arrowHoc`? Well to figure that out first you'll need to inspect the exports of `module` to determine the type of `arrowFn1`, then you can know the type of `arrowHoc`.

If you use variables for indirection, you need to maintain a separate, strict contract for your HOC.